# Count down timer to stop counting C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
public partial class gamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    DispatcherTimer countDownTimer;
    public gamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        countDownTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        countDownTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        countDownTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(countDownTimerEvent);
        countDownTimer.Start();



        txtHit.Text = "0";
        txtCountdown.Text = "" + "seconds remaining";
    }

    int buttonCount = 0;
    string stringButtonCount = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count = 15;


    void countDownTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    txtCountdown.Text = count + " Seconds Remaining";


        if (count > 0)
        {
        count--;
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/highScore.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            count = 15;
            buttonCount = 0;
            stringButtonCount = "";
        }
   }
```

Everything is working fine, except the fact that the timer keeps on going. After I leave the page, the timer keeps on counting. I have code on another page that re-routes it back to this page. The count variable then resets to 15 and counts down, but since the timer is based on the countDownTimer the whole 15 seconds does not go down. I have found countDownTimer.Stop(), but I am not sure where to place it. I'm a beginner on windows phone. I know this is an easy problem, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I will better delete this answer, to not stimulate this kind of behaviour (in any sense). Please, use SO as intended in the future (just for being practical if you want; with this attitude you would not get any help, at least, from me).

Comment: No big deal of question/problem: the Stop() method for the timer (which, logically, has to be declared such that it can be "seen" from the given method; in this case, at the class level) has to be called once the timer stops being useful. In the OP's code this happens when entering into the "if (count == 0)" condition in "countDownTimerEvent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the *OnNavigatingFrom* method on mainpage where you can stop the Timer.